# ChainedTransactionManager is not rolling back DB Transaction during kafka transaction failure

Tags: spring-kafka

I was trying to implement chainedTM (for a DB Transaction followed by Kafka Transaction). I have followed the doc here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#ex-jdbc-sync.

After implementing I created test where I intentionally fail the kafka transaction to ensure the DB Transaction is getting rolled back but it's NOT happening like that so. Need some help.

Here is my configuration code

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class KafkaConfig {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConfig.class);

@Autowired
private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;


@Bean
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props =
            new HashMap<>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties());

    props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG,
            true);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 0);
    return props;
}


@Bean
public Map<String, Object> producervdtConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props =
            new HashMap<>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties());

    props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG,
            true);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 0);

    return props;
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, let> producerFactory() {
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, let>(producerConfigs());
    factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return factory;
}

@Bean(name = "chainedlbrTM")
public ChainedTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager(JpaTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                                           KafkaTransactionManager<String, let> kafkaTransactionManager) {
    return new ChainedTransactionManager(transactionManager, kafkaTransactionManager);
}


@Bean(name = "chainedvdtTM")
public ChainedTransactionManager chainedvdtTransactionManager(JpaTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                                           KafkaTransactionManager<String, vet> kafkavdtTransactionManager) {
    return new ChainedTransactionManager(transactionManager, kafkavdtTransactionManager);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, let> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<String, let>(producerFactory());
}

@Bean
public KafkaTransactionManager<String, let> kafkaTransactionManager() {
    KafkaTransactionManager<String, let> ktm = new KafkaTransactionManager<String, let>(producerFactory());
    ktm.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
    return ktm;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTransactionManager<String, vet> kafkavdtTransactionManager() {
    KafkaTransactionManager<String, vet> ktm = new KafkaTransactionManager<String, vet>(producervdtFactory());
    ktm.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
    return ktm;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory em) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(em);
}


@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, vet> producervdtFactory() {
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, vet>(producervdtConfigs());
    factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, vet> kafkavdtTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<String, vet>(producervdtFactory());
}
```

My Service class

```java
@Service("libraryService")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class LibraryServiceImpl
    implements ILibraryService
{
    @Autowired
    private LibraryRepository libraryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private IEventProducer producer;

    @Override
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "chainedLibraryTM")
    public Library createLibrary (final Library library)
        throws LibraryAlreadyExist
    {
        LOG.debug("Creating library {}:{}", library.getName(), library.getVersion());
        final Library result = libraryRepository.createLibrary(library);
        producer.libraryCreated(result);
        return result;
    }
```

my EventProducer

```java
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, LibraryEvent> kafkaTemplate;


public void libraryCreated(final Library library)
    {
        sendMessage(EventType.CREATED, library);
    }

    private void sendMessage(final EventType type, final Library library) {
        LOG.info("Sending {} event for library {}, topic = {}", type, library.getId(), topic);
        final LibraryEvent event = LibraryEvent.newBuilder()
                .setLibraryId(library.getId())
                .setLibraryName(library.getName())
                .setLibraryVersion(library.getVersion())
                .setEventType(type)
                .build();
        LOG.trace("Kafka Record: {}", event.toString());
        ProducerRecord<String, LibraryEvent> record =  new ProducerRecord<String, LibraryEvent>(topic, library.getId().toString(), event);
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, LibraryEvent>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(record);
        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, LibraryEvent>>(){

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, LibraryEvent> result) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            }
        });

        if (future.isDone()) {
            try {
                future.get();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new KafkaException("Interrupted", e);
            }
            catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw new KafkaException("Send failed", e.getCause());
            }
        }
```

My Test

```java
@Test
    public void testArt() throws Exception {
          library2 = this.libraryService.createLibrary(
                new LibraryBuilder()
                        .name(tid)
                        .version("1.0")
                        .artifact(
                                new ArtifactBuilder()
                                        .name("TestP")
                                        .tag(P)
                                        .content("first content")
                                        .build())
                        .artifact(
                                new ArtifactBuilder()
                                        .name("TestF")
                                        .tag(F)
                                        .content("first content")
                                        .build())
                        .build());
```

After enabling the logging level noticed the below logs. Exception is due to config I set (props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 0);), this is to make kafka transaction fail so that it will rollback DB.

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.184+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Exception thrown when sending a message with key='1' and payload='{\"libraryId\": 1, \"libraryName\": \"ware\", \"libraryVersion\": \"1.0\", \"eventType\": \"CREATED\"}' to topic pr-rt-deploy:","logger_name":"org.springframework.kafka.support.LoggingProducerListener","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 139 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.\n","tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.194+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Unable to post deploy event for library 1, topic = pr-rt-deploy, due to = Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 139 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration. .","logger_name":"events.EventProducerImpl","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.195+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Completing transaction for [service.LibraryServiceImpl.createLibrary]","logger_name":"org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.201+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Clearing transaction synchronization","logger_name":"org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.202+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@421d8c5] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@40617316] from thread [Test worker]","logger_name":"org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.205+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Initializing transaction synchronization","logger_name":"org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.205+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Triggering beforeCommit synchronization","logger_name":"org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.206+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization","logger_name":"org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.206+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Initiating transaction commit","logger_name":"org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.213+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Triggering afterCommit synchronization","logger_name":"org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.213+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Clearing transaction synchronization","logger_name":"org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.214+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Triggering afterCompletion synchronization","logger_name":"org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.214+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Removed value [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaResourceHolder@31ab2fab] for key [org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory@1e34605e] from thread [Test worker]","logger_name":"org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.216+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction","logger_name":"org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.216+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Initializing transaction synchronization","logger_name":"org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"tenantId":"ware","opcRequestId":"1234"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-30T11:18:42.247+05:30","@version":"1","message":"DataSourceManager shutdown started ..","logger_name":".infra.datasource.DataSourceManager","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@EnableTransactionManagement` must be on a `@Configuration` class, not `@Component`s (`@Service`).

If you enable TRACE logging for `org.springframework.transaction` and `org.springframework.kafka.transaction` you will see all the transaction behavior.

**EDIT**

> `kafkaTemplate.send(record);`

Sends are asynchronous. You are not checking the status of the send (e.g. 
`kafkaTemplate.send(record).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` so the exception is not propagating to the listener container.

Some errors (such as the one you are causing) are detected immediately rather than asynchronously. I recently added code to the `KafkaTemplate` to detect these "immediate" failures and throw an exception.

I am not sure what version you are using, but [this change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1438) is in the latest version of all supported branches (2.4.x, 2.3.x, 2.2.x, 1.3.x).

But, in any case, you need to get the result of the send in case there is an async error.

Comment: I have removed the @EnableTransactionManagement as requested, but still noticing the DB Transaction is not rolling back. Enabled the logs and pasted above.

Comment: You are not waiting for the result of the send; see the edit to my answer.

Comment: I made the change as you suggested, now the exception is propagating. I am able to notice the DB transaction is getting rolled back. But I am surprised, for the same scenario the DB transaction is getting rolled back just by using @Transactional. I mean without Configs I had (ChainedTransactionManager, KafkaTransactionManager, jpaTransactionManager, @ EnableTransactionManagement ... etc). So I would like to understand what's the use of all these beans ChainedTransactionManager, KafkaTransactionManager, jpaTransactionManager if I am able to achieve just by adding @Transactional?

Comment: For producer-only transactions, if you start a JPA transaction with `@Transactional` the `KafkaTemplate` will synchronize the kafka transaction with the JPA transaction with the JPA transaction committing first and then Kafka. If the JPA commit fails, the kafka commit will roll back. The chained transaction manager allows you to control the order of the commits. With your configuration (Kafka second), the Kafka transaction will commit first.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed my actual kafka server to bootstrap-servers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers} and now I am noticing it's failing with below exception org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not create Kafka transaction; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000milliseconds while awaiting InitProducerId;   Number of alive brokers '1' does not meet the required replication factor '3' for the transactions state topic (configured via 'transaction.state.log.replication.factor').

Comment: I googled the above error and it's asked to set the below properties in application.yml. But that didn't help either.                                                  
transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1 and transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1

Comment: See [this test case for an example for testing transactions with a single embedded broker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/TransactionalContainerTests.java#L113-L116).

Comment: Thanks Gary, I was able to run my test cases. But one more question, I have edited my EventProducer class above. future.addCallback we are adding the callBacks and making it async, and after adding future.get we are making it sync. Will this be blocking? or Can we modify this?

Comment: No; because you are checking `isDone()` before calling `get()` (which won't block if `isDone()` is true.

Comment: Also, from the above code, Does chained transactions work both ways? I mean what if db transaction fails, kafka transaction will be rolled back?

Comment: Hi Gary,  Also you mentioned this code is for immediate failures (sync). What will happen if there are some asynchronous failures?  May be if you can give some examples tests on some async failures, I can write tests related to that. Do we need to specify time always whenever we do future.get. like - future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)? Sorry for too many questions :)

Comment: >`Does chained transactions work both ways?` No; it is "Best Effort IPC" - see [this article](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html). If an async problem happens, the commit will fail and the container will rewind and replay the record(s). I don't know of an easy way to test that, except with mocks. It's generally a good idea to use get with a timeout, but it is not necessary if you test `isDone()` first.